# Wordpress - How can I register a custom taxonomy with the search query param 'tag' in URL and make it work?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I registered a custom post type e.g **animal**, registered a taxonomy **animal_tag** who's query_var is **tag**. Added posts and assigned theme tags.

Now filtering posts in:

/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=animal&tag[0]=funny&tag[1]=lovely

returns no posts.

But changing the query_var to somethings other than **tag**, e.g. tags, _tag when registering the taxonomy returns the right number of filtered posts e.g.

/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=animal&_tag[0]=funny&_tag[1]=lovely

My intuition is that Wordpress is doing some shenanigans with my taxonomy, when queering posts.

So how can I make a custom taxonomy with the search query param 'tag' in URL work?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has several Reserved Terms that are not to be used in either a GET or POST (including query strings):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#reserved-terms

You just have to rename it, like you discovered. But this, hopefully at least, explains why.